# Docker based Web Hosting

Tags: docker

I am posting this question due to lack of experience and I need professional suggestions. The questions in SO are mainly on how to deploy or host multiple websites using Docker running on a single Web Host. This can be done, but is it ideal for moderate traffic websites.

I deploy Docker based Containers in my local machine for development. A software container has a copy of the primary application, as well all dependencies — libraries, languages, frameworks, and everything else.

It becomes easy for me to simply migrate the “docker-compose.yml” or “dockerfile” into any remote Web Server. All the softwares and dependencies get installed and will run just like my local machine.

(Say) I have a VPS and I want to host multiple websites using Docker. The only thing that I need to configure is the Port, so that the domains can be mapped to port 80. For this I have to use an extra NGINX for routing.

But VPS can be used to host multiple websites without the need of Containerisation. So, is there any special benefit of running Docker in Web Servers like AWS, Google, Hostgator, etc., OR Is Docker best or idle for development only in local machine and not to be deployed in Web Servers for Hosting.

Comment: The benefit is not having to deal with Linux's configuration yourself, and instead use a more or less simple config of containers running in a stable and tested environment

Comment: And also intensive development and deployment is simpler via Docker Hub + layers

Comment: Use LXD for all the *host* containers then use docker inside the containers, then use nginx to forward.

Comment: Why do you want to run Docker containers inside LXD containers @LawrenceCherone?

Comment: Nothing to do with isolation..good luck installing 20 projects using docker compose on all running on port 8080

Comment: You mean to say there is no performance issues with this setup. I thought, Docker is ideal for Development in Local Machine. This means - I can now use a CI/ CD Pipeline (Jenkins) and transfer code from Local Machine to Web Host. It is same as having a Dedicated Host, if I am hosting a Single Website.

Answer (score 6):

The main benefits of docker for simple web hosting are imo the following:

- **isolation** each website/service might have different dependency requirements (one might require php 5, another php 7 and another nodejs).
- **separation of concerns** if you split your setup into multiple containers you can easily upgrade or replace one part of it. (just consider a setup with 2 websites, which need a postgres database each. If each website has its own db container you won't have any issue bumping the postgres version of one of the websites, without affecting the other.)
- **reproducibility** you can build the docker image once, test it on acceptance, promote the exact same image to staging and later to production. also you'll be able to have the same environment locally as on your server
- **environment and settings** each of your services might depend on a different environment (for example smtp settings or a database connection). With containers you can easily supply each container it's specific environment variables.
- **security** one can argue about this one as containers itself won't do much for you in terms of security. However due to easier dependency upgrades, seperated networking etc. most people will end up with a setup which is more secure. (just think about the db containers again here, these can share a network with your app/website container and there is no need to expose the port locally.)

  Note that you should be careful with dockers port mapping. It uses the iptables and will override the settings of most firewalls (like ufw) per default. There is a repo with information on how to avoid this here: https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker

Also there are quite a few projects which automate the routing of requests to the applications (in this case containers) very enjoyable and easy. They usually integrate a proper way to do ssl termination as well. I would strongly recommend looking into [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) if you setup a webserver with multiple containers which should all be accessible at port 80 and 443.

Comment: So, I presume it is not just for a simple website or a single website (running on a dedicated host) - Docker makes it idle because of easy configuration, transportability, reproducibility, separation of concerns etc. Otherwise I had to configure the whole machine in a specific way for the website. The only new difference I can see is - instead of using Linux commands directly in the host console, I have to first get inside the Container and execute the commands.

Comment: You usually wouldn't execute any commands inside the docker container. The common way is to build your ready to be deployed docker image once (or preferably have your CI/CD system build it) -> push that image to your registry (or dockerhub) -> deploy it on acceptance/staging -> run your acceptance tests against the deployed environment -> promote this image to production

Comment: Also imo your unit tests should be part of the docker image build. (I a way that it fails if they are unsuccessful)

Comment: I am personally using the same process even for simple websites. In that case the image is usually just an nginx with some html, js and css copied into it... (example with a static react build: https://github.com/leoek/material-safety-search/blob/develop/frontend/Dockerfile) Even for a simple website I can still reuse the routing and ssl termination the reverse proxy does for me and this simple website does not need to care about it. Also I'll be able to spin this container up anywhere I want and it is ready to use.

Comment: But doesn't this redirection/ routing using NGINX effect your search engine performance. Normally we should avoid these redirections and proxy.

Comment: Having a reverse proxy on the server which routes the request based on the domain is necessary anyways as there are other website running on it too (just with different domain names) and all requests are received at port 80/443 no matter which website they belong too. And even if I had only a single nginx with all websites that nginx must route the requests according to the domain. Also modern reverse proxies are so fast that you probably wont be able to measure any significant difference compared to a request which is directly handled by the webserver (in this case the nginx).